# complex query in left join in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a query like

```
SELECT a.id, a.code, b.id as bid FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.code BETWEEN b.start AND b.end
```

Now How can I convert this to laravel eloquent query?

**what I have tried?**

```
A::leftJoin('b', function($j){
   $j->on() //here I face complexity. How I implement it
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me

```
A::leftJoin('b', 'a.code', 'BETWEEN', DB::raw("a.code BETWEEN b.start AND b.end"))->get();
```